# prevent window.opener.location.href form reloading parent

Tags: javascript

I am opening a window on a page and when the user finishes filling out the form there is some logic that says

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
```

This reloads the parent url.  Is there anyway the parent document can prevent child windows from refreshing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have control over the child window, I think the best you can do, is unsetting the reference to the parent.

```
var child = window.open(someUrl);
child.opener = undefined;
```

You might break functionality in the child window though. E.g. the line you mention, will result in an error. On the other hand, you are sure that the parent won't be refreshed.

Comment: that doesn't work if there's a redirection inside the popup, it seems window.opener is reset to the reference to the parent =(